# Sending large strings through TCP - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, tcp, base64, tcpclient

I developed a simple TCP client on Windows Phone, as shown [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

This is working just as expected.

Now, I want to send very large **Base64** strings though this client (for transferring images).
But, when I try to send **Base64** strings from this client, I only receive a portion of the string at the server, due to which I'm not able to generate the entire image at the server.

The server side code for receiving strings is:     **(Edited)**

```
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Any;

            Console.Write("Port No. (leave blank for port 8001): ");
            string port;
            port = Console.ReadLine();

            if (port == "")
                port = "8001";

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, int.Parse(port));

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();                

            Console.WriteLine("\nThe server is running at port " + port);
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("\nWaiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("\nConnection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[5 * 1024 * 1024]; // BIG SIZE for byte array, is this correct?
            String message = String.Empty;

            int k = s.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("\nRecieved...");
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                message += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Message.txt", message);  // write it to a file

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSent Acknowledgement");
            /* clean up */
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();
```

I'm really stuck here.
Please help me.

I think the problem is with the client and not the server.
Please assist me.

The class I've used in the client can be found at the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) referred to above.

PS: I've already tried to increase the values of **TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS** and **MAX_BUFFER_SIZE** in the class. But it did not help.

**Update:**

Here's some client side code ([look here on MSDN for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)):

```
        // Make sure we can perform this action with valid data
        if (ValidateRemoteHost() && ValidateInput())
        {
            // Instantiate the SocketClient
            SocketClient client = new SocketClient();

            // Attempt to connect to the echo server
            Log(String.Format("Connecting to server '{0}' over port {1} (echo) ...", txtRemoteHost.Text, ECHO_PORT), true);
            string result = client.Connect(txtRemoteHost.Text, ECHO_PORT);
            Log(result, false);

            byte[] bytearray = null;

            // Attempt to send our message to be echoed to the echo server
            Log(String.Format("Sending '{0}' to server ...", txtInput.Text), true);
            if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)  // this checkbox is for image selection
            {


                // This is the part where we send images


                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)image1.Source);

                    wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)wbitmp.PixelWidth, (int)wbitmp.PixelHeight, 0, 10);
                    bytearray = ms.ToArray();
                    string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);                        

                    result = client.Send(str);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\nMessge sent:\n\n" + str + "\n\n");
                }                                        
            }
            else
            {
                result = client.Send(txtInput.Text);
            }

            Log(result, false);

            // Receive a response from the server
            Log("Requesting Receive ...", true);
            result = client.Receive();
            Log(result, false);

            // Close the socket connection explicitly
            client.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Client-Side is able to send large Base64 Strings?

Comment: Are you sure you're not closing the socket on the client side before everything's gone through? I suggest you use something like Wireshark to see what data is actually being sent.

Comment: If you think the client-side is the problem, where is the client-side's code?

Comment: Jon is most likely right - TCP is "polite" protocol, thus fire and forget is not working like in UDP and disconnect events might overtake network buffers. The proper way is to have a protocol where the server confirms to the client that all data has been received. In the mobile world it might also help to do a size sanity check of the protocol.

Comment: TCP will usually (attempt to) ensure all data went through before fully processing a disconnect (Unless the system that hasn't finished receiving data tries to do a send)

Comment: I've added some client code above and updated the server code, please check 'em. I don't think that client-side is able to send the entire Base64 string.

Comment: The client-side code is all fine. Not the best, but it's fully capable of sending the data. It's **definitely** the server at fault here.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva: Did you see the SocketClient.cs class that I've used in the Client? If not, please see it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx . I suspect that there is some problem related to the TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS and MAX_BUFFER_SIZE constants in the Class.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I keep telling you, look at the answer I wrote below... the problem is, again, **definitely** the server. (Or, failing that, both client and server are a problem. Either way, the server is bad.)

Comment: @Smartis: I've confirmed that the client is sending the entire **Base64** string (using Windows Simple TCP Services as the server). So, it is clear that the problem is with the server.

Answer (score -2):

```
                    while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                        totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                    }
```

Edit: now that section of code has been reduced down to only

```
        int k = s.Receive(b);
```

is bad: it assumes all the data sends perfectly in one go, which isn't how networking works.

Two options:

- At the start of the string, include how long it should.
- At the end of the string, have an end symbol (a null perhaps) that won't be anywhere else in the message

Then that while loop should keep going until either the entire length is found or the end symbol is found.

(Also, sending Base64 is a bad idea when you can avoid it. Why not send as a stream of raw bytes?)

[ED: This portion is no longer relevant](Also, why is the server choosing where to save the file [and delaying everything until the server makes a pick] - the client should indicate where to save it at the start, and then the server merely sanity checks it. [Unless you have a very good reason not do it that way])

EDIT: a quick simple implementation of what I was saying:

This server code

```
        int k = s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("\nRecieved...");
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            message += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
        }
```

change to

```
        while (true)
        {
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("\nRecieved...");
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                char bc = Convert.ToChar(b[i]); // This is a very wrong way of doing this but it works I guess meh.
                if (bc == ' ')
                { // You've struck the end! Get out of this infinite loop!
                    goto endmyloop;
                }
                message += bc;
                Console.Write(bc);
            }
        }
        endmyloop:
```

This piece of client code

```
                result = client.Send(str);
```

change to

```
                result = client.Send(str + " ");
```

-- Base64 can never have a space in it, so that will be used to mark the end.

Be warned that if the client errors (and doesn't send a space at the end for some weird reason), this code will be trapped in the while loop forever (zero-CPU-usage infinite-wait)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried using Windows Simple TCP Services as a server (instead of mine) and it worked perfectly. So, it is clear that the problem is with the server. But, can you help me to read the string character by character instead of using `int k = s.Receive(b)`, so that I can receive the contents in a loop, and break the loop when end of string character (appended manually) is received.

Comment: You can achieve it with only a few minor edits to your current code. See my edit the answer above. Honestly, your entire existing code and the very basic ideas put into it are heavily flawed... but there's no point trying to explain it all here. Just keep practicing C# and reading tutorials!

Comment: I'm new to networking in C# and I don't have much experience, so it may so happen that I'm using bad practices!
Well, anyway, I've already tried the method you stated here but it did not work. It runs in an infinite loop (and the space is sent through the client, I verified it using Simple TCP services as the server). I think the problem arises because of the fact that the entire stream is fetched only once at: `int k = s.Receive(b);` and we are receiving the same thing (the truncated string) everytime in an infinite loop, right?

Comment: @ShrayanshSharma - just to be sure, can you use the OP's code combined with my exact code how I wrote to insert it, without changing it yourself, and tell me how that goes? -- also assuming `TcpListener.Receive` does the same as the underlying `Socket.Receive`, it should only ever return the same chunk of text twice of the same chunk of text was sent twice.

Comment: I've tried using your code as it is without making any changes. But it runs in an infinite loop, may be because we're receiving it all in just one statement: `int k = s.Receive(b);`. The `while` loop below that is just to read what we've stored in the byte array (if you see, we're just reading the byte array in the loop). So the problem lies in the statement: `int k = s.Receive(b);`. Instead of receiving it all in just one statement, is it possible to receive it character by character?

Comment: Nonononono! `The while loop below that is just to read what we've stored in the byte array` you copied my code wrong then! I said to put `int k = s.Receive(b);` /inside/ the `while` loop, so it keeps receiving new chunks until it reaches the end. ... er, could you maybe post the full source (or a download link to it) so maybe I could look at it and test it myself?

Comment: I used your code as it is, with the line `int k = s.Receive(b)` inside the `while` loop but trust me, it runs in an infinite loop.
Anyway, here's full server code: 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/33z33t

Comment: I meant the client source actually. My tests of the server code (and a custom client I made myself, as I don't have yours) all work perfectly. Here's the entire program I used: http://pastebin.com/Q8TJa8yY -- it works perfectly, and sends a full 10KB worth of data. It takes two `Receive()` calls to complete.

Comment: Forgot to link @ShrayanshSharma

Comment: I've used the same client code as shown here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Just made some little changes to send Base64 strings. (Look at the original question above to see the changes I've made).

But, I think the client is working perfectly as I've tested it with Windows Simple TCP Services (as the server). Yes, it sends the entire Base64 string. The problem is certainly with server.

Comment: Hey @mcmonkey4eva, am I bothering you? I really want to do this, that is why I'm not giving up. Please be patient. Now, in the line (in client) `wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)wbitmp.PixelWidth, (int)wbitmp.PixelHeight, 0, 10);`, when I increased the last parameter (i.e. quality) from 10 to 85 (or even as low as 20), then I was not receiving the entire **Base64** string at the server even with Windows Simple TCP services as the server. It means that there is some fault at the client too! Can you help me to modify the code so that I can send the string character by character?

Comment: @ShrayanshSharma - could you please upload your code, exactly how it is, with all your exact modifications? Or at least the entirety of the function you're putting all the networking code in? (You have part of it in the OP, but that's outdated and incomplete) --- er... you /have/ modified the client from what's in the OP, right?

Comment: Okay, then. Here's full client code - **MainPage.xaml.cs** : http://pastebin.com/xj2bF9pn


**SocketClient.cs** : http://pastebin.com/L5EXDFWx

Now, please help me find the problem. I really need it.